# debugging a c++ program withing R

Tags: c++, r, debugging, gdb, rcpp

I'm running a c++ program from R using Rcpp and RcppArmadillo. My OS is windows 8. I use the cxxfunction to compile my code (Later I'll make a package directly instead, but for now I'm clueless about how to make a package). The issue is that R often crash while running my c++ code. There must be some segmentation faults because often it doesn't exactly crash at the same spot even with the same seed. Currently, I'm printing out stuff to the prompt but I feel like this is not the most efficient way to debug my program.

So I read a bit about how to debug c++ code in R and it seems that gdb is a good way to do it. So I downloaded mingwin32 which contains gdb for windows. When I run R using gdb it works fine and I can run all my code fine but when R crash gdb backtrace function returns 'no trace'. I have no idea why. I heard people say to add the option -g -Oo in the compilation, but I'm using cxxfunction to compile my c++ program and I don't know how to compile manually things in R. I also heard some people talk about changing cxxflags but I don't really understand what that is and how to change it.

So my questions are :

1. Should I use gdb or something else?
2. How do I get gdb to work with my R program?
3. Should I install linux on a separate partition to make everything simpler?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Definitely yes to #3 -- debugging is much easier on Linux. And your hunch is right, you want to compile your program with `-g -O0`, or perhaps `-g -Og` to make sure debugging the necessary debugging symbols are present.

Comment: Yes, but on Linux it is still pain.  But you do get `R -d gdb` -- yet using gdb is all that trivial.

Comment: I'll download ubuntu then.

Comment: Good move. You can even use it in a virtual environment while being in Windows.  BTW, I missed a 'not' there -- gdb takes some learning too.  And you could try a frontend to gdb such as ddd, cgdb, xxgdb ...